# dcast long to wide by transforming unique RHS

Tags: r, data.table

Let's say I have a table like the following:

```
DT <- data.table(ID1= rep(c("a","b","c"),3),ID2=rnorm(9,4),var = 1:9)

## > DT
##    ID1      ID2 var
## 1:   a 2.630392   1
## 2:   b 3.966620   2
## 3:   c 4.002776   3
## 4:   a 3.188372   4
## 5:   b 4.735084   5
## 6:   c 4.307198   6
## 7:   a 2.830868   7
## 8:   b 4.892684   8
## 9:   c 3.429826   9
```

and I would like to perform a dcast with the by taking into consideration only the number of times that each ID1 apprear.

undesired output:

```
dcast(DT,ID1~ID2)
```

desired output:

```
##    ID1 1 2 3
## 1:   a 1 4 7
## 2:   b 2 5 8
## 3:   c 3 6 9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
dcast.data.table(DT[,N:=1:.N ,ID1], ID1~N, value.var='var')
#   ID1 1 2 3
#1:   a 1 4 7
#2:   b 2 5 8
#3:   c 3 6 9
```

Comment: I was thinking of something like this. but didn't know about the `.N` . It escaped me in the doc. thanks

Comment: @DJJ The idea is to create a sequence column.  Another option would be `library(splitstackshape);  dcast.data.table(getanID(DT, 'ID1'), ID1~.id, value.var='var')`

Comment: I tend to prefer the data.table option, but the second one can be handy in other situations as well. Many thanks to you.

Comment: @DJJ, `getanID` is essentially the same thing as "the data.table option" :-)